# SetTimeout() in node js

Tags: node.js

when we call setTimeout(func, millSec) does the program stop executing for a specified millisecond or It keep executing normally and simply call the function after the specified time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Simple definition

setTimeout() schedules a function to be run after a minimum threshold in ms has elapsed. Timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).

> when we call setTimeout(func, millSec) does the program stop executing
>   for a specified millisecond

No, It put that function into the stack and run Timer and  pick next task

[image]

[Source](https://gist.github.com/thinker3197/473ea38daaec4f6b5d7783e0ffc57a21)

There is a concept of Events which emit the event when the task is completed and then that function put into the Event loop if Call Stack is clear then the task is process from Event loop and put into Call Stack to execute

[image]
[Source - freecodecamp](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/javascript/concurrency-model-and-event-loop/)

> and simply call the function after the specified time.

Yes, it calls once its push from Event loop to Call Stack, But Timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).

Useful links

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 0):

The Timers module in Node.js contains functions that execute code after a set period of time. Timers do not need to be imported via require(), since all the methods are available globally to emulate the browser JavaScript API. To fully understand when timer functions will be executed, it's a good idea to read up on the the Node.js Event Loop.